# "No active iOS device found" when trying to access simulator logs

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

Somehow when I run `npm run log:ios` (`react-native log-ios`), I get the following error:

`No active iOS device found`

I have the simulator up and running with the app open.
Any idea why, or how can I start to investigate this issue?

**PS:** I recently installed Xcode 9.1-beta2 as I wanted to check something inherited from this upgrade. Not sure what role it would/could have played in this case.

Comment: If you have a similar issue with `react-native log-ios`, just know you can open the simulator log via the menu **Debug** > **Open System Logs...**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9441) with `react-native log-ios` has not been resolved yet due to some other priorities. There is a simple workaround using [Console.app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuhoY.png). To open `Console.app`:  `⌘` + `space` > type `console`, press enter.

Simulator log can also be seen under `Debug` > `Open System Log`

Edit: If you want to see `console.log` for debugging in iOS Simulator

Open `Safari`, Go preferences -> advanced -> `Show Develop menu` in the menu bar. Once done, build and run in Xcode and then in safari go `Develop` -> `iPhone Simulator` -> `Your App Name`.

Comment: On my Simulator, my app name is in grey and can't be clicked. Under it, there is a clickable JSContext option, If I click on it I see many things but not the logs

Comment: If you're not seeing the output of `console.log` it's probably because you have 'Evaluations' and 'Errors' selected. Change it to 'Logs' or 'All'.